# Visibility = Collapsed not working in DockPanel

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visibility

I'm trying to get the below TextBlocks to become Collapsed, however it isn't working:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False" >
<DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ReferenceValues" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Resources>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropFullName}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropTitle}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropUserName}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropYear}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropEmailAddress}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropStartingPage}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropEndingPage}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropStartingDate}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropEndingDate}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropLastUpdate}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ReferenceValues}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding PropFileFormat}" Margin="2,2,2,2"  Visibility="Visible"/>
...
</DockPanel>
```

They just appear as white space when the values are `null` or `""`. Does a `DockPanel` automatically not render controls that are not displayed? (Only 3 `TextBlocks` can fit in 72 pixels.)

Comment: The value of a property is determined by the Dependency Property Value Precedence. See this link from msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit setting of the Visibility property on each `TextBlock` is overriding the style. Remove the `Visibility="Visible"` property and the TextBlocks will render as expected based on your styles.

If you want the default Visibility to be Visible, then set the default in the style:

```
<Style x:Key="ReferenceValues" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```